Need help sorting a Lua table
I am trying to sort this table by ID but I can't seem to figure it out, is there anyone out there that can assist me? Thank you in advance.
Here is my code it basically grabs the item id as x and then reads the tooltip for item x then sends the tooltip data into the item x:
function ess(x)
    if not ITEMSCRAPESTATS  then
        ITEMSCRAPESTATS = {}
    end
   ES:SetHyperlink("item:"..x..":0:0:0:0:0:0:0")
   for i=1, ES:NumLines() do
       local text = _G["ESTooltipTextLeft"..i]:GetText()
       if _G["ESTooltipTextLeft2"]:GetText() then
       ITEMSCRAPESTATS[x] = ITEMSCRAPESTATS[x] or {}
       table.insert(ITEMSCRAPESTATS[x], _G["ESTooltipTextLeft"..i]:GetText())

       else
       ITEMSCRAPESTATS[x] = ITEMSCRAPESTATS[x] or {}
       table.insert(ITEMSCRAPESTATS[x], "No Stats for Item Number")
       end
   end
    if _G["ESTooltipTextLeft2"]:GetText() then
      print("Scraping Stats for Item Number: "..x)
      else
      print("No Stats for Item Number: "..x)
      end
end

This is what ends up in the table:
ITEMSCRAPESTATS = {
    [60002] = {
        "Goldroar Signet", -- [1]
        "Binds when picked up", -- [2]
        "Unique-Equipped", -- [3]
        "Finger", -- [4]
        "+1 Strength", -- [5]
        "Item Level 15", -- [6]
        " ", -- [7]
    },
    [60004] = {
        "Divining Rod", -- [1]
        "Binds when picked up", -- [2]
        "Ranged", -- [3]
        "9 - 17 Fire Damage", -- [4]
        "(8.7 damage per second)", -- [5]
        "Requires Level 6", -- [6]
        "Item Level 12", -- [7]
        " ", -- [8]
    },
    [60001] = {
        "Goldroar Band", -- [1]
        "Binds when picked up", -- [2]
        "Unique-Equipped", -- [3]
        "Finger", -- [4]
        "+1 Intellect", -- [5]
        "Item Level 15", -- [6]
        " ", -- [7]
    },
    [60003] = {
        "Waterlogged Dirge", -- [1]
        "Binds when picked up", -- [2]
        "Two-Hand", -- [3]
        "17 - 26 Damage", -- [4]
        "(7.2 damage per second)", -- [5]
        "+1 Strength", -- [6]
        "+1 Stamina", -- [7]
        "Requires Level 6", -- [8]
        "Item Level 10", -- [9]
        " ", -- [10]
    },
    [60000] = {
        "Resilient Poncho", -- [1]
        "Binds when picked up", -- [2]
        "Back", -- [3]
        "20 Armor", -- [4]
        "+1 Spirit", -- [5]
        "Requires Level 6", -- [6]
        "Item Level 26", -- [7]
        " ", -- [8]
    },
}

I would like it to sort like this:
ITEMSCRAPESTATS = {
    [60000] = {
        "Resilient Poncho", -- [1]
        "Binds when picked up", -- [2]
        "Back", -- [3]
        "20 Armor", -- [4]
        "+1 Spirit", -- [5]
        "Requires Level 6", -- [6]
        "Item Level 26", -- [7]
        " ", -- [8]
    },
    [60001] = {
        "Goldroar Band", -- [1]
        "Binds when picked up", -- [2]
        "Unique-Equipped", -- [3]
        "Finger", -- [4]
        "+1 Intellect", -- [5]
        "Item Level 15", -- [6]
        " ", -- [7]
    },  
    [60002] = {
        "Goldroar Signet", -- [1]
        "Binds when picked up", -- [2]
        "Unique-Equipped", -- [3]
        "Finger", -- [4]
        "+1 Strength", -- [5]
        "Item Level 15", -- [6]
        " ", -- [7]
    },
    [60003] = {
        "Waterlogged Dirge", -- [1]
        "Binds when picked up", -- [2]
        "Two-Hand", -- [3]
        "17 - 26 Damage", -- [4]
        "(7.2 damage per second)", -- [5]
        "+1 Strength", -- [6]
        "+1 Stamina", -- [7]
        "Requires Level 6", -- [8]
        "Item Level 10", -- [9]
        " ", -- [10]
    },  
    [60004] = {
        "Divining Rod", -- [1]
        "Binds when picked up", -- [2]
        "Ranged", -- [3]
        "9 - 17 Fire Damage", -- [4]
        "(8.7 damage per second)", -- [5]
        "Requires Level 6", -- [6]
        "Item Level 12", -- [7]
        " ", -- [8]
    },
}

I cant seem to get it to sort by the ID

Your table ITEMSCRAPESTATS is not a sequence, instead, it is a dictionary.
A regular Lua table (which essentially is a set of "key-value" pairs) is stored unsorted.
In other words, Lua does not know that table key 60004 is greater than 60001. Lua does not even know that these keys are comparable.
Any Lua value (a number, a string, a function, another table) could be a table key.  How to compare a function with a string to determine which is greater?  No way.  So, there is no order of keys exists by default.
Only sequences do have natural order of keys.  A sequence is a Lua table with integer keys starting with key 1 without gaps.  And you have to use ipairs instead of pairs to traverse all keys in their numeric order.  Do you have all missing keys 1-59999 present in your table?
So, try to enforce the order you expect:
for key = 60000, 60004 do 
   do_smth_with(t[key])
end

You may also read all the keys, collect them in an array, sort the array, and access the main table in that order of keys:
-- collect all keys
local all_keys = {}
for key in pairs(t) do
   table.insert(all_keys, key)
end
-- sort keys
table.sort(all_keys)
-- traverse table in that order of keys
for _, key in ipairs(all_keys) do
   do_smth_with(t[key])
end


Use this
  table.sort(ITEMSCRAPESTATS, function(a,b) return a[key] > b[key] end)

